# Product Description is not showing on product page

Tags: magento2, product, product-page, product-description

Getting my webstore up and going. Just noticed that I don't have a product description tab. Only the more information tab is showing. I am using the Luma theme and the only changes I have made are to the final_price block for configurable products. Any ideas on where to look or how to fix this issue?
[image]

Comment: If you have not added any description in the product then it won't display here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not added any description in the product then it won't display here.

OR

May be the description block was removed from the layout of the catalog product view.

Please look for block `name="product.info.description"`if anywhere in the theme or module is removed.

OR

You can also check by editing the product if block is removed from this particular product page.

> Goto Edit Product > Design > Layout Update XML

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I tried going back to the Magento Blank theme and still have the problem. I searched my IDE and found the block in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: Thanks that was it ! In Magento 2.4.3 under Design -> Layout was set to "Product -- Full width" after changing this to 1 column the tabs showed again